# Creating NSDate from Int components

Tags: ios, swift

I have a calendar with which I select a date:

```
func SACalendarDate(calendar: SACalendar!, didSelectDate day: Int32, month: Int32, year: Int32) {
    var date = Date.from(year: Int(year), month: Int(month), day: Int(day))

    print("\(year) and \(month) and \(day)")

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
    formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
    let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(date)

    buttonSelectDates.setTitle("\(dateString)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    getUsers(date)
}
```

When I feed "date" in this method:

```
class func from(#year:Int, month:Int, day:Int) -> NSDate {
    var c = NSDateComponents()
    c.year = year
    c.month = month
    c.day = day

    var gregorian = NSCalendar(identifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    var date = gregorian!.dateFromComponents(c)
    return date!
}
```

I get a date that is one day behind: selectedDate: 2015-07-14 22:00:00 +0000
And the parameters are: 2015, 7 and 15. Why does this happen?

Comment: because of time zones, you probably live in a time zone +2 hours. (or -2 hours, it always confuses me)

Comment: but the ints don't consider the time zone..

Comment: But `NSCalender` does, you create 2015-07-15 00:00:00 +0200 because you live in that timeZone and NSCalender transforms that to something with +0000, which is exactly two hours earlier.

Comment: Thanks Luke for your answer

Comment: P.S. Anyone who downvotes at least please give reasons, seems a perfectly legit question to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDate` is just a single point in time represented as seconds since 1.1.1970, it does not care about timezones or anything - its "timezone" is GMT and is +0000 (no offset). If you create a `NSDate` from a calendar with the local timezone, for example +0200 that timezone offset will be taken off the actual date you provide to represent a point in time without any timezone. To get a readable date representation of the `NSDate` back you need to use a `NSDateFormatter` which knows your current timezone:

```
let date = from(2015, month: 7, day: 15)
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"

print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))
print(date)
```

You will receive the following printed output:

> 2015-07-15 00:00:00 +0200
>   2015-07-14 22:00:00 +0000